# rules for text analytics to spin the text

Tags: nlp, analytics, stanford-nlp, text-analysis

I was thinking on how text spining applications works. Like some applications which takes text and gives similar meaning text which changing theme (by using synonym, passive sentences etc).

First looking at it I thought just changing the words with their synonym will do it. But later I realized that is not sufficient.

Can someone help me to define text analytics rules for text spining?

1. Collceting noun, adjectives from text and replacing it with it's synonym.

any reference to similar tutorial will also help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this discussion: [I wish to create a system where I give a sentence and the system spits out sentences similar in meaning to the input sentence I gave](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21990004/3279460)